# Hide status bar in only one fragment and display it on the others

Tags: android, xml, fragment, statusbar

I have 3 fragments in my activity and I want to make one fragment full screen by hiding the status bar. When I exit that fragment, the status bar should reappear. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Its always better to define a function in your parent activity which will have the code to hide the status bar and calling that in your target fragment will hide the status bar for that fragment and when you are exiting the fragment in its stop method you can show the status bar again.

Let this be your method in activity,

```
public void hideStatusBar()
    {
     // your code depending upon what you have implemented
    }

 public void showStatusBar()
        {
         // your code depending upon what you have implemented
        }
```

and then on fragment resume you can call this method like this,

```
((ParentActivity)getActivity()).hideStatusBar();
```

and to show it again for other fragment you can override the onStop of fragment,

```
((ParentActivity)getActivity()).showStatusBar();
```

Answer (score 1):

Visit  https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html
and 
https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/visibility.html

clearly explained how to hide and show statusbar in different android versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to programmatically clear flags set with setSystemUiVisibility(), you can do so as follows:

```
activity?.window?.decorView?.systemUiVisibility = 0
```

https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/dim

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin** version of show/hide-ing status bar from fragment

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    (activity as MainActivity).supportActionBar?.hide()
}
```